# By counting by 2 ways, show a cycle of four acquaintances exists

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, combinations

In a conference there were $35$ participants. There are $110$ couples who know each other. Prove that it is possible to choose 4 members to sit at a round table such that two people sitting close together know each other.

This is the last problem in a workbook "Solving combinatorial math by 'counting in two ways' " by Nguyen Tang Vu (original [here](https://www.mathvn.com/2019/12/giai-toan-to-hop-bang-phuong-phap-em.html) in Vietnamese, Problem 10 on page 62) "published in the math journal Star Education." I find it quite interesting because it can't be solved in the usual ways.

Here's all I did:

Suppose any $2$ people can't get along with $2$ other people.
Count the number $S$ of triples of the form $(A,B,C)$ where person $A$ and person $B$ are familiar with person $C$.

Method 1: Count by $A, B$. We have $S \le \binom{35}{2}$ (according to the assumption)

Method 2: Count by $C$:
Let $a_i$ be the number of people who know the $i$-th person. We have:
$$ a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{35} = 220 $$

So $\binom{a_1}{2} + \binom{a_2}{2} + \binom{a_3}{2} + \ldots + \binom{a_{35}}{2} \ge 585$.

I want to prove what I assume is wrong, but $\binom{35}{2} = 595$ is still greater than $585$. I tried to tighten my inequality but I can't. Can anyone give me a hint, please?

Comment: Hint: pigeonhole

Comment: can you be more specific, i got your suggestion and thought for more than 2 hours but still not solved the problem

Comment: I have shown everything I try to do. hope to get help from everyone

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks for updating your Question.  I've applied some $\LaTeX$ syntax.  Please review to make sure I did not change your meaning unintentionally.

Comment: This seems to be a problem that cuts close to the bounds on edges in a square-free graph.  See this [OEIS A006855 sequence](https://oeis.org/A006855) and its references.  So it's likely as "the last problem in my workbook" meant to test your patience in sharpening the inequalities.  In any case I'm trying my hand to get a proof.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't studied graphs yet. However, you can give me any answer that you can, I thank you very much for that.

Comment: @DonThousand help me ! can you be more specific?

Comment: @hardmath help me please !

Comment: What your technique of "counting by 2 ways" proves is that if there were 111 pairs of acquaintances at a conference with 35 participants, then four people could be chosen to sit together at a round table with all four of the adjacent pairs known to each other.  But you've said the "last problem in my workbook" asks what if there were only 110 pairs of acquaintances. It is possibly a problem that requires extensive computer checking.  What is the name and author of your workbook?

Comment: @hardmath it was a famous teacher of my country. This problem was the last one in his documentation that I found on the internet. The title is: Solving Combinations by 'counting in two ways'

Comment: @hardmath okay. I believe you . https://www.mathvn.com/2019/12/giai-toan-to-hop-bang-phuong-phap-em.html    .Lesson 10 at the end of the document. I translated the title above

Comment: I reached out to the author to check if the 110 couples who know each other should have been 111.  I'll let you know what he says.

Comment: Yes, the author confirmed that it should be 111 couples who know one another.  If you like I can write up an Answer to elaborate on the details of how your approach works and gets the proof when that change is made.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks very much . the 111-pair case I can easily handle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate difficulty can be explained as a mistake in the problem statement.  The author wrote me (via Facebook Messenger), "it's my mistake, exactly is $111$ pairs," rather than the $110$ couples noted in the Question.

The general problem:

> For $n$ conference participants, how many couples $f(n)$ could be known to each other without including a "cycle" of four who could be seated with each between two of their acquaintances?

is actively studied in the combinatorial research literature, e.g. [Extremal Graphs Without 4-Cycles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4912).  Readers should not be put off by the vocabulary of graph theory to discuss these problems.  The participants form the *vertices* of a graph whose *edges* are the pairs of people who know one another.

Assume for a graph with $n = 35$ vertices that there are no $4$-cycles. Then any two vertices $A,B$ will have *at most* one adjacent vertex in common; if they share two distinct "neighbors" $C,D$, altogether they would form a $4$-cycle subgraph (which we assume does not exist):

$\require{AMScd}$
$$ \begin{CD}
A @>>> C\\
@AAA @VVV\\
D @<<< B
\end{CD} $$

So the count $S$ of all undirected paths of length two, like $A\frac{\phantom{XXX  }}{\phantom{XXX}}C\frac{\phantom{XXX}}{\phantom{XXX}}B$ , is bounded above by the count of unordered pairs $\{A,B\}$ of vertices, $\binom{35}{2}$. Thus $S\le 595$.

We have the second way to count $S$.  Consider for each vertex $C$ how many distinct pairs of neighbors $A,B$ it has that form a path of length two, $A \frac{\phantom{XXX  }}{\phantom{XXX}} C \frac{\phantom{XXX}}{\phantom{XXX}} B$.  Thus, using the Question's notation $a_i$ for the numbers of neighbors at each vertex:

$$ S = \sum_{i=1}^{35} \binom{a_i}{2} $$

We don't know exactly what all the *vertex degrees* $a_i$ are, so we can't directly evaluate $S$ from the above. But we do know by the [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) that the sum of all the $a_i$'s is twice the number of edges.

If there are $111$ edges, $S$ must be at least the minimum of the expression above where $\sum a_i = 222$.  The minimum would be attained by spreading the degrees as equally as possible among the $35$ vertices, namely twelve vertices of degree $\lceil 222/35 \rceil = 7$ and the other $23$ vertices of degree $\lfloor 222/35 \rfloor = 6$.  So $S \ge 12\binom{7}{2} + 23\binom{6}{2} = 597$.

Since that contradicts the previous upper bound on $S$, we know that $111$ edges on $35$ vertices guarantees a $4$-cycle subgraph, which is what the (corrected) problem calls for.  However it leaves the interesting problem as originally stated (with $110$ edges) unsolved; can a $4$-cycle be avoided with only $110$ edges?  I did not find a definitive answer in researching this Question.